# Fastest way to get the last row in a postgreSQL database table without modifying table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datatable, row

I have a table, and I need to get the last cell of a column in it. The table is large though, and I want to do it as quickly as possible.
The trick is that the newest rows (largest timestamp) are added to the bottom of the table. So I really just need to figure out the fastest way to get the last row. I'd like to do this without making an index or permanently modifying the table or creating tables(EDIT: I'm open to making views)

I've tried this: 
`SELECT my_column FROM my_schema.my_table ORDER by timestamp DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1`
but it was really slow for the large table

so I tried this:
`SELECT my_column FROM my_schema.my_table WHERE timestamp=(select max(timestamp) from my_schema.my_table)`

and it felt even slower.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need an index on that column

Comment: For my general culture, is it possible to set a partial index that will "point" to the most recent row? Such an index would use almost no space and updating it would be costless. Does PostgreSQL (or any other RDBMS) handle such a feature?

Comment: Create index on that column

Comment: sorry, I"m pretty uneducated on SQL. how do I create an index? Does it require permanently modifying the table?

Comment: Yes/no it requires creating an index on the table: [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) for postresql shows how

Comment: Ok, I'm interested in the fastest way to do this without modifying the table. I'll update my question accordingly

Comment: An index on `my_column` makes no sense, create an index on the timestamp column.

Comment: Who said to add an index on "my_column?"  comments said "that column" which I took to mean timestamp

Comment: what makes you think new rows are inserted at the bottom of the table?.. you have no updates/deletes?..

Comment: A table doesn't have a bottom, nor a top. It's just a bubble of data. If you need an order, you have to sort your data. Always. If you don't, you might be lucky, but don't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little tricky way and keep your last inserted row in a separate table.

Notice, that the `INSERT` query can return values:

```
INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *;
```

Now you can use it and save new row in a separate table:

```
INSERT INTO my_schema.my_table_last_row(INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *);
```

The table `my_table_last_row` should have the same columns (or can just `INHERIT` from the original table).

You could use a trigger `ON INSERT` to do the job.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remember_last_row()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE my_schema.my_table_last_row;
    INSERT INTO my_schema.my_table_last_row VALUES(NEW.*);

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$

CREATE TRIGGER remember_last_row_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON my_schema.my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE remember_last_row();
```

I think that this is the fastest way of getting the last row inserted without any modifications to the original table (including adding an index).

Of course things get complicated if you update that row - you would need to keep the copy updated as well.

---

Simpler solution - store just the last timestap ;)

Comment: Thanks for putting so much thought into this Adam. Unfortunately I'm trying to minimize the changes I make to this database as a whole. It's generated by an api to track analytics events, and I want to try to accomplish my goals by just reading the tables.